# Access: notify when linked table source changes structure?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007

I have imported a table in Access 2007 through Oracle ODBC. My problem is that sometimes the tables change structure in Oracle (eg new columns are added) and when that happens Access doesn't automatically pick up the changes in its linked table.
Instead it keeps using the old structure and even worse some rows simply won't show up in the Access queries (I don't know why?).

The other problem is that I don't have any control over the Oracle DB so the changes can happen any time. Manually updating the linked tables all the time is too much of a hassle. Is it possible to somehow set Access up to notify me of the changes? I mean, somehow Access must be able to tell that something has changed - the question is; can it tell me?

Regards,
John

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the tables in VBA and refreshing the link? I am not completely sure, but I think it will work. The code can  run when Access is opened.

Answer (score 1):

Run this function - you can either link it to a form Open event, or just run it when you need to refresh the data

```
Sub relinkTables()
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        ' check if table is a linked table
        If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
            tdf.Connect = "your odbc connection string to the DSN or database"
            tdf.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why reset the connection? Are you sure that is necessary?

Comment: @Remou paranoia?   I suppose the Connect string can be left out, but it can also be reconstructed if the location of the linked database moves